# Changing variables in a loop

Tags: python, loops, scripting, for-loop

I have a variable:

```
user = "jobrr"
```

And I want to loop the following but change what the variables represent after each loop cycle (so in the loop predefine what the variable for the coming loop will be)

```
example loop as long as y = true
    openurl = urllib.urlopen("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&contributor_details&include_rts=true&screen_name="+user+"&count=3600")
    user = user + "a" #just for example
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
user = 'username'
y = True

while y:
    openurl = urllib.urlopen("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&contributor_details&include_rts=true&screen_name="+user+"&count=3600")
    user += "a"
    #You have to do something in here to change y or this will be an infinite loop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
user = 'username'
y = True

while y:
    openurl = urllib.urlopen("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?include_entities=true&contributor_details&include_rts=true&screen_name="+user+"&count=3600")
    user = function_that_returns_user_name()
```

you only need to define `function_that_returns_user_name()`

Comment: I feel that this method is more sustainable for longer term development (I doubt you'll get a true match on names that append just 'a's to it).

Comment: @Makoto, I agree, that's why I wrote my answer. but the OP has the choice. :-)